# How to download multiple files in JS

Tags: javascript, window.open

I'm opening download links with:

```
window.open(url,"_self")
```

This works for one download link. But for all other links opened under one click they are caught by Chrome Popup Blocker.

I need this feature because I want to implement a button on my site which downloads multiple files at once. Like This data consists of data1.cab data2.cab data3.cab and I don't want user to download them one by one but instead single download link for downloading full dataset.

Comment: Pages don't usually mass-start downloads. Browsers, security and privacy plugins will probably resist this, especially if each download is not started by a user action (such as a click). Can you `zip` the files in advance?

Comment: No I cannot zip the files, beacause in many use cases the files are large up to many GBs.

Comment: Probably best to say "your files are here: link1 link2 link3" as as stated above most browsers will block multiple downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an undesired behavior which will be detected by all Pop-Up blockers. Single click can create single action. Also downloading multiple files can hide many files from user and look like malware attack.

Best way is to zip files or if zipping is unavailable show all the files with their own download link. This way the user knows what is he downloading.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a desirable behavior as the User may think of it as a malware/Virus attack. 
You can use https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ JSZip library to zip the files (images data) and then stream the zipped file at the client location 
Sample example

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
var img = zip.folder("images");
img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true});
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {
    // see FileSaver.js
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
});
```

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up; this solution has nothing to do with streaming. The entire zip must exist in memory before any of it is saved to disk...

Answer (score 0):

There are a new API which we can use to access local file system.
I've submitted an answer to the same question like this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68827689/885694).