# PHP - display multiple PDF urls in one

Tags: php, pdf, merge, fpdf

I have several paybills listed and each one of them redirects to an URL to a pdf refering to them (ex: bill 1: https://bill/381032, bill 2: https://bill/98231).

I have a web page in which the user can select the bills he want through a checkbox, what I want is for the selected urls to be merged in a single pdf, this way he would be able to view/print the listed pdfs in just one file.

I've tried usinf FDPD but couldnt find a way, does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You can either [zip them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11541030/231316), [merge them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4794435/231316) or use [JavaScript to download multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68827689/231316)

Comment: I used [libmergepdf](https://packagist.org/packages/iio/libmergepdf)