# JS library for downloading multiple files utilizing File System API (FileSystemDirectoryHandle)

Tags: javascript

as part of a pure HTML+JS gallery in the browser, I'm looking for a way to download multiple files at once (without having to zip them on the client/server side).

The [File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API)  with the [FileSystemDirectoryHandle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryHandle) and [window.showDirectoryPicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showDirectoryPicker#browser_compatibility) seems to be a way to do exactly this, by allowing the user to select a directory and then create files in that directory.
E.g:

```
async function storeFileInDirectory() {
    const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker(dirPickOpts);
    const testFile = await dirHandle.getFileHandle("test.txt", {create: true});
    const writable = await testFile.createWritable();

    // Write the contents of the file to the stream.
    await writable.write("Test content.");
    
    // Close the file and write the contents to disk.
    await writable.close();
}
```

**But I could not find a libray that does this.** Is there a library available for this kind of application that will register a worker, download a list of files in the background and save them to disk? (Maybe also resume a previously interrupted download)

The best code I found was this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68827689/4682543), but this is more a prototye.

PS: I'm aware that the required [window.showDirectoryPicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showDirectoryPicker#browser_compatibility) doesn't work in Firefox at the moment (Firefox 120). But providing this feature at least for the Chromium browser would already help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As I was not able to found one, I created my own:

https://github.com/ccvca/js-multi-file-download